# Haml how to put dynamic value in CDATA

Tags: haml

I would like to produce the following with haml:

```
<awesome>
<![CDATA[
  awesome awesome awesome awesome awesome awesome 
]]>
</awesome>
```

My (false) assumption was that something like this would work:

```
%awesome
  :cdata
    = "awesome "*6
```

However it instead puts a literal equals sign and text after instead of interpreting it,

```
<awesome>
  <![CDATA[
    = "awesome "*6
  ]]>
</awesome>
```

`:cdata="awesome"*6` results in an error.

How do I put dynamic text in CDATA tags when using haml?

(Please note I do not have the luxury of rails)

Comment: how are you rendering your file? who is your host? we need to know more than just not rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MZaragoza was almost right, but the output of his still included equals signs and quotes. To embed data in haml's `:cdata`, you must use string interpolation, which has the same syntax as ruby's string interpolation: `#{code} data`.

```
%awesome
  :cdata
    #{'awesome ' * 6}
```

yields the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and looks good for me

I hope that adding the output into a string interrelation would help

```
%awesome
  :cdata
    = "#{'awesome ' * 6}"
```